# Changing MySQL database from utf8_general_ci to utf8_bin - Good idea?

Tags: mysql

I recently learnt that if you do not want MySQL to read å as an a or ö as an o, you need to use the uft8_bin collation.

My site is multi-tenant so not everyone needs the utf8_bin collation. Some of my customers are in Norway and Finland and they require these "non-english" characters to be ordered correctly.

But would it be a good idea to set the tables to utf8_bin anyway?

Or is there a better way such as setting the collation to utf8_bin only if they are a non-english country?

Will this affect anyone from an English country or does utf8_bin act the same as utf8_general_ci but has the added bonus of ordering å, ö, etc correctly?

Or is there a better option than utf8_bin?

Answer (score 2):

`utf8_general_ci` orders å and ö correctly. The difference between the `utf8_*_ci` and the `utf8_bin` collations is that the former is *Case-Insensitive*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In case you are unaware, in Norway, the letter ä comes after z. But with `utf8_general_ci`, it puts ä in with the other a's. Here's an SQL Fiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9572e/1

Comment: @BenSinclair: `utf8_general_ci` is a generalized case-insensitive one. I'm trying to find the whole list, but if you have something like phpMyAdmin, pick a Norway-specific `utf8_*_ci`.

Comment: @BenSinclair: There's `icelandic`, `latvian`, `romanian`, `polish`, `estonian`, `spanish`, `swedish`, `turkish`, `czech`, `danish`, `lithuanian`, `slovak`, `roman`, `persian`, `esperanto`, `hungarian`, and `sinhala`.

Comment: @BenSinclair: But the point being, if you didn't *want* case-insensitivity in the first place, choose `utf8_bin` by all means :) If you do, though, just change it to `utf8_danish_ci`.

Comment: Thanks again :) Sorry if I'm a bit stupid when it comes to all this. Being a 'multi-tenant' site, what would be the best option so that it orders the letters correctly for whatever language is used? I just used `utf8_general_ci` because that's all I knew at the time which is now why I want to do the right thing from now on so all languages appear as they should. Perhaps running COLLATE in each SQL statement depending on their language? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html

Comment: @BenSinclair: I have no clue :) If COLLATE in each statement works, go for it! But I think `utf8_general_ci` is supposed to be the "one size fits all" collation, so if it doesn't work, I don't believe that there is a better choice in that regard.